# I need my code to Add and bind data to the gridview in asp web form

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, gridview

I don't know what's wrong with the code i've tried to search for possible reasons but haven't figured out yet what's the problem actually.Now the issue is that my web form contains a gridview in which i've place a footer row which will allow the user to add the data and that data gets added to the database and gets binded to the gridview after clicking on the insert link button,But the problem comes when i fill the data and when press link button insert it adds the data twice in gridview and in database too everytime.Below is my whole code which is performing CRUD operation on gridview:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" EnableViewState="false" />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="AutoId" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" AllowPaging="true"
            PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" ShowFooter="True" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">

            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnInsert" runat="server"
                            CommandName="Insert">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AutoId" DataField="AutoId" ReadOnly="true" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# Eval("FirstNAme") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# Eval("LastName") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# Eval("Age") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' Columns="3" />

                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="REw" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAge" Text="*" />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# Eval("Active").ToString().Equals("True") ? "Yes" : "No" %>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropActive" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Active") %>'>

                            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" />

                            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" />

                        </asp:DropDownList>

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlactive" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" ForeColor="Red" CommandName="Delete" />

                        </span>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#efefef" />

            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />

            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />

            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />

            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateData();
            }

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            this.PopulateData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            this.PopulateData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            var autoID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
            {

                string sql = "Delete from PersonalDetail" +

                " where AutoId = @AutoId";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@AutoId", autoID);

                    conn.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

            lblMessage.Text =
            "Record has been deleted successfully !";

            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.
            Color.Red;

            this.PopulateData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.PopulateData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            var autoID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex] as GridViewRow;

            TextBox tFirstName = row.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;

            TextBox tLastName = row.FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox;

            TextBox tAge = row.FindControl("txtAge") as TextBox;

            DropDownList dropActive = row.FindControl("dropActive") as DropDownList;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
            {

                string sql = "Update PersonalDetail set FirstName = @FirstName,LastName=@LastName, Age= @Age, Active = @Active" + " where AutoId = @AutoId";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@FirstName", tFirstName.Text.Trim());

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@LastName", tLastName.Text.Trim());

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Age", tAge.Text.Trim());

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Active", dropActive.SelectedValue);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@AutoId", autoID);

                    conn.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

            lblMessage.Text =
            "Record updated successfully !";

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

            this.PopulateData();
        }
        private void PopulateData()
        {

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
            {

                string sql = "Select * from PersonalDetail";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {

                    using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {

                        ad.Fill(table);
                    }
                }
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = table;

            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
            {
                TextBox name = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox lname = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtlname");
                TextBox age = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtlage");
                DropDownList isactive = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlactive");
                using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PersonalDetail(FirstName,LastName,Age,Active) VALUES('" + name.Text + "','" + lname.Text + "','" + age.Text + "','" + isactive.SelectedItem.Value + "')",conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            lblMessage.Text =
            "Record has been Added successfully !";
            this.PopulateData();
            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.RowCommand -= GridView1_RowCommand;
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
        {
            TextBox name = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox1");
            TextBox lname = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtlname");
            TextBox age = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtlage");
            DropDownList isactive = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlactive");
            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PersonalDetail(FirstName,LastName,Age,Active) VALUES('" + name.Text + "','" + lname.Text + "','" + age.Text + "','" + isactive.SelectedItem.Value + "')",conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        lblMessage.Text =
        "Record has been Added successfully !";
        this.PopulateData();

    }
```